# Is it possible to display Extension information on Google Chrome Mac TouchBar? if not, what about network calls on the touchbar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am trying to come up with a way of having the touch bar on my mac display the network calls being made on the page I am navigating, I already have an extension that captures the exact network calls i need so If it is easier to just have an extension pass information to the mac touch bar then that would be even better.

I already tried using BetterTouchTool without luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Chrome extension platform does not have TouchBar support. You may be able to accomplish your goal by creating a native app in Objective C or Swift and using the [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to share data between your extensions and application.